# Could Azure CLI upload/update a script which was code by azure cli and powershell?

Tags: azure, azure-powershell, azure-cli

Could Azure CLI upload/update a script which was code by azure cli and powershell?

e.g
there's a demo.ps1:

```bsh
$json = az group list;
sendemail --body $json --to "xxxx@google.com" --title "xxx";
```

I'd like to upload demo.ps1 & create a taskjob on azure like

```sh
az somecommand create task --time "every 3 hour" --file demo.ps1
```

upload taskjob like :

```
az somecommand update task --time "every 3 hour" --file demo.ps1
```

What I've tried & know :

- I tried automation runbook but it `can't support azure cli`
- I tried azure logic but it `only support javascript`
- I can create a ubuntu VM and use crontab to do it, but it's too heavy for light job

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's meaningless to upload scripts scheduled, but it meaningful to run scripts scheduled.

As you know, Azure automation runbook don't support Azure CLI.
But **power shell con do most jobs CLI do**, you can try using power shell command in runbook, and **link schedules** to run the scripts.

Comment: thanks, I upvoted it, but you can't create corntab on cloud shell

Comment: @Wei , sorry for the valid solution before, I update my answer, please check.